# Referring to input function of another Snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

I'm having problems referring top the input function of another Snakemake rule.
I illustrated this in the code below:

```
rule bla:
    output: '{x}.txt'
    shell: 'touch {output}'


rule all_dogs:
    input: expand(rules.bla.output, x=['goofy', 'buster', 'fifi'])

rule all_cats:
    input: expand(rules.bla.output, x=['tom', 'felix', 'sylvester'])

def all_birds_infun(wildcards):
    return expand(rules.bla.output, x=['tweety', 'donald'])

rule all_birds:
    input: all_birds_infun

rule all_mammals:
    input: rules.all_dogs.input,
           rules.all_cats.input

rule all_animals:
    input: rules.all_dogs.input,
           rules.all_cats.input,
           rules.all_birds.input

localrules: bla
```

The rule `all_mammals` refers to the inputs of two other rules and works fine. The rule `all_animals`, however, does not work because it refers to the input of `all_birds`, which uses an input function as a rule. I realize that as a workaround, I could simply refer to the input function `all_birds_infun` directly, but in my real world example that would mean copy&pasting some parameterized functions, which would be very ugly.

The error I get from referring to `rules.all_birds.input` is

```
TypeError in line 25 of Snakefile:
expected string or bytes-like object
  File "Snakefile", line 25, in <module>
```

Comment: My guess is that when the `input` of a rule is a function of wildcards, it needs the wildcards to be determined in order to be resolved into actual file names. This process is something local to the rule, based on how its outputs were matched against the names of desired files. When you refer to `all_birds.input` outside of `all_birds`, the resolution of the input into actual file names does not happen. I don't know what would be the implications of changing this behaviour, but it might be worth mentioning your example in an issue on the snakemake github.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/515).

Comment: The above question is about a Snakemake bug/limitation. If you came here wanting to see how to refer to input of another rule, this simpler question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68215369/7483211