# Refer to input or output files of another Snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

How can I programmatically refer to attributes of another Snakemake rule? What do I need to replace `<whatever is in test1's input>` with, for this to work?

```yaml
rule test1:
    input: 'a.txt'

rule test2:
    output: <whatever is in test1's input>   <---- ?
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other rules can be referred to by `rules.<rule_name>` as explained in the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rule-dependencies). However, the rule that's referenced needs to come first, that is be defined above the rule that's referencing:

```yaml
rule test1:
    input: 'a.txt'

rule test2:
    output: rules.test1.input  <---
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```